# Using mouse click to plot points in R

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data.frame

```
         x1       x2
1   9.50000000 -10.5000000
2   9.50000000  -4.5998399
3   9.50000000  -2.1671763
4   9.50000000  -1.0030305
5   9.50000000   0.6213049
6   9.50000000   0.6666270
7   0.05162178   0.6660570
```

I would like to plot in a 2 dimension as follows: Plot point `(9.50000000, -10.5000000)` then after one click adding the point `(9.50000000,  -4.5998399)` in the graph, after another click adding point `(9.50000000,  -2.1671763)`, etc.

Comment: I am curious, what do you mean with "using mouse"? I do not think I get what you are asking, could you be more precise? thank you

Comment: I second @SabDeM. Explain what you're trying to accomplish. Base R plots are not supposed to be a presentation tool (which is what you seem to be looking for). If that's the case, you should check R Presentations or Shiny.

Comment: Look up `getGraphicsEvent` It should do what you want.

Comment: I mean using mouseclick. I supppose that I should use manipulatemouseclick() but all my tries to use it were unsuccessful.